# How handle error in promise await and not break another promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have async function:

```
 async getLayers() {
     let arr = [];
     try {
     let thematicLayers = await new ThematicLayers(this.userRoles).get();
     let customLayers = await new CommonLayers(this.userRoles).get();

     arr.push(thematicLayers);
     arr.push(customLayers);

     } catch(err) {
        console.log('_________________');
        console.log(err);
     }
}
```

If at least one  promise returns exception it comes to `catch()`.  How to run `await new ThematicLayers` and `await new CommonLayers` independencty, now `await new CommonLayer` await `await new ThematicLayers`.

And how to handle case if one promise if succuss, another not?

Comment: maybe they will need to be in separate try/catch blocks?

Comment: Put them in two separate `try/catch` blocks?

Comment: Yes, I think about it, is it beaty way? And how to run them independenly?

Comment: why not use `let thematicLayers = await new ThematicLayers(this.userRoles).get().catch(e => {})`?

Comment: @daddygames Because `new ThematicLayers` may or may not return a reject. He does not specify.

Comment: it can return or resovle or reject

Comment: Oh then do what @daddygames suggested. All day.

Comment: How to run them independently?

Comment: expand on what you mean by "independently." They are already independent. They just wait for one to finish before the next executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Promise.all
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
 Promise.all([
    new ThematicLayers(this.userRoles).get(),
    new CommonLayers(this.userRoles).get()
 ]).then(value =>
 {
    console.log(value);
    // your code
 }, reason =>
 {
    console.log(reason)
    // your code
 });
```

Comment: I need to execute them independently, in your case in another one fails it means all promise all fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of using await, resolve the promises with .then, like so:

```js
 let thematicLayers = new ThematicLayers(this.userRoles).
 
 thematicLayers.get().then(response => {
  arr.push(response);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
;
 let customLayers = new CommonLayers(this.userRoles)
 
 customLayers.get().then(response => {
     arr.push(response);
 }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```